# Automatically renames files with correct file extention in bulk

Tags: file-extension, batch-rename, exiftool

I have a folder with multiple types of file ( mp4, mp4, jpg, wma .etc) and these files have either have no extension, or all messed up extensions extension such as mp3.mp3, mp3.jpg, or just file name.  I was reading that exiftool or even python magic can be used to assign correct file extension on understanding filetype. I am looking for exiftool based solution where these file can be renamed with correct file extension.

eg 
filename (this is mp3 file)
filename1.jpg ( this is again mp3 file, with jpg as file extension)
filename.mp3.mp3.mp3 (repetition of extension)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about programming. Please ask on superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

At the simplest, try this (change double quotes to single quotes if on Mac/Linux):
`exiftool -ext "*" "-filename<$filename.$filetype" TargetDir`
or
`exiftool -ext "*" "-testname<%f.$filetype" TargetDir`

That will simply add the extension all the files in TargetDir.  To recurse, add `-r`.  If there was already an extension, this will add the proper extension at the end of the false extension e.g. filename.mp3 would become filename.mp3.jpeg.

For a more complex version which strips away some of the previous, false extensions, you could try something like this:
`exiftool -ext "*" "-filename<${filename;s/(\.(mp3|mp4|jpe?g|png|wma|mov))*($)//i}%-c.$filetype" TargetDir`
which would strip away extensions that are in the center parens in the regex.  The `%-c` will add a number if the resulting rename would be a duplicate e.g. filename.jpeg, filename-1.jpeg, … filename-n.jpeg.

*Edit:* added `-ext` option to deal with files without an extension.